# Trivial mistake (syntac) with RenewDocummentCommand vs newdocument commant

Tags: xparse

I had this :

```
\let\otitle\title
\renewcommand\title[2] {\otitle{#1 \\ \bigskip \large #2\\ \bigskip}}
```

worked fine, modified it to this (xparse):

```
\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m m} {\otitle{#1 \\ \bigskip \large #2\\ \bigskip}}
```

Intending to add optional parameters and other xparse functionality, however it actually errors out on

```
\title{Notes for Grade 7 Math, 2020}
{
   Complied from the 2013 Curriculum Guide
  \thanks{Thanks to Gereina Skanes for presentation and formatting review} 
}
```

which worked fine previously. Thought I understood the syntax of RenewDocumentCommand?

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to help.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you cite the error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\title` is a robust command and `\let` doesn't copy such commands correctly. You can use `\LetLtxMacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\otitle\title

\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m m} {\otitle{#1 \\ \bigskip \large #2\endgraf \bigskip}}

\title{abc}{cde}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

In the next LaTeX release there will a `\NewCommandCopy` command that you can use too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewCommandCopy\otitle\title %new in the next latex ...
\RenewDocumentCommand\title{m m} {\otitle{#1 \\ \bigskip \large #2\endgraf \bigskip}}

\title{abc}{cde}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, but why the change to \endgraf?

Comment: there should be no newline command if you don't have following text.